# Hide option menu when UITextField text is selected

Tags: swift, uitextfield

Simply how do we prevent this pop up menu when UITextField text is selected.

[image]

Desired functionality:

user can tap either field and edit text.
When field is tapped and textField is empty, i have text generated then textfield.selectAll(self). This is the point that the menu pops up.

[How to disable UITextField editing but still accept touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116969/how-to-disable-uitextfield-editing-but-still-accept-touch) answers do not resolve this issue nor allow user to still use the textField.

Comment: Do you want the text to be selectable at all?

Comment: `textFieldName.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable UITextField editing but still accept touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116969/how-to-disable-uitextfield-editing-but-still-accept-touch)

Comment: No, I want user to be able to select text and edit. But I have zero use for “copy,paste,cut,lookup...” options. This pop up menu is just clutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the response:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716228/2129911

When using textField.selectAll(), passing the textField's delegate makes the pop up menu appear.

For no popup menu use textField.selectAll(nil)